# Linked anchor position is too high

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I have a header (fixed) on top of the page with multiple div rows.
When a button is clicked the page transitions to the target div. using JQuery.
The transition works fine, but the beginning of the div goes behind the header to the top of the page.
How can I identify where to stop the scroll up to?

Here is my JQuery:

```
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
            && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var $target = $(this.hash);
              $target = $target.length && $target
              || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $('html,body')
                .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
               return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Off-topic: Use ID values on wrapper elements rather than named anchors. It allows for better positioning and is a more modern technique.

Comment: Another off-topic: if working with a CMS, use a custom html5 attribute like 'data-hash' instead of comparing against ID so that content editors have control over the target mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Since the header is fixed, you have to take into account the height of the header because it is part of the page's viewport now, instead of inside the natural flow of the document:

**Code**

```
$('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $target.offset().top - $mainNav.height()
}, 500);
```

($mainNav being your fixed nav)